# NSTableView binding + delegate causes array index error

Tags: binding, delegates, nstableview

I have a view-based NSTableView which uses bindings to an NSArrayController.

As soon as I add a delegate to the table view, I start getting:

```
Ignoring exception raised in void run_cocoa_block(void *): *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

and

```
MyApp[59144:25384659] *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
MyApp[59144:25384659] (
    0   CoreFoundation    0x00007fff93410452 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib   0x00007fff9601af7e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation    0x00007fff93327775 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 245
    3   AppKit            0x00007fff9bd7ad31 -[NSTableRowData _addViewToRowView:atColumn:row:] + 535
    4   AppKit            0x00007fff9bd7a98e -[NSTableRowData _addViewsToRowView:atRow:] + 184
    5   AppKit            0x00007fff9bd791a7 -[NSTableRowData _initializeRowView:atRow:] + 390
    6   AppKit            0x00007fff9bd77907 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:] + 416
```

If I remove the delegate connection, everything works fine... the table fills properly from the NSArrayController that it is bound to, and the cells/columns get the correct data as well.

I need the delegate to use

```
-(BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
```

What might be causing this?

Elsewhere in the app, I have a sheet that also uses a view-based NSTableView with bindings and it works fine with a delegate.

Comment: What happens if you don't implement `control:textShouldEndEditing:`?

Comment: Same crash - it never gets to that delegate method

Comment: Which `NSTableViewDelegate` methods are implemented?

Comment: none - the docs say that if I am using bindings, I don't need to provide a rowView delegate. This works with no delegate methods elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awakeFromNib:, I was calling:

```
[[self itemsController] setContent:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

this worked in a cell-based NSTableView but not in a view-based one. I'm not sure why, but giving it this empty array may have been happening after the binding took place but before the OS did something else with it and the empty array was confusing it.